# rewrite typescript paths on rollup build

Tags: typescript, rollup

I have a typescript project which I consume as a lib in other projects.
I'm using the `paths` like so:

tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@components": ["./src/components/index.tsx"]
    }
  }
```

When building the project using `rollup` the imports from `@components` are breaking other projects depending on this lib, as there is no `@components` package.

How can I rewrite the module imports or what is the best practice to use alias?